# getting unexpected token error while running subquery in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to run a subquery in hibernate, But i am getting

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 
where near line 1, column 183
```

First here the query in SQL

```
select * 
from OS_Historystep hs1
where step_name = '011' 
and finish_date = (select max(finish_date) 
                      from OS_Historystep hs2 
                      where hs2.step_name = hs1.step_name
                      and hs2.ref_id = hs1.ref_id);
```

why i am getting this error ? Here is my hibernate query

```
StringBuffer query2 = new StringBuffer();
    query2.append(" from ");
    query2.append(WflWorkflowHistoryStep.class.getName());
    query2.append(" hs1 where hs1.stepName = " + workFlowStepName);
    query2.append(" and hs1.finishDate = (select max(hs2.finishDate) from "
            + WflWorkflowHistoryStep.class.getName() + " hs2 )");
    query2.append("where hs2.stepName = hs1.stepName and hs2.refId = hs1.refId");

    try {

        historyStepList = getHibernateTemplate().find(query2.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {

        String message = e.getMessage();
        System.out.println();

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write out your query like this:

```
 from WflWorkflowHistoryStep hs1 
where hs1.stepName = ?
  and hs1.finishDate=(select max(hs2.finishDate) from WflWorkflowHistoryStep hs2)
                                                                                ^
where hs2.stepName = hs1.stepName and hs2.refId = hs1.refId
^^^^^
```

you see that you've got a two where clauses.  I think you probably meant to put your bracket elsewhere.

Also, use parameters (`?`) instead of concatenating strings, otherwise you open yourself up to HQL injection attacks.

Comment: thanks :) The query should be `query2.append(" from ");
  query2.append(WflWorkflowHistoryStep.class.getName());
  query2.append(" hs1 where hs1.stepName =  ?");
  query2.append(" and hs1.finishDate = (select max(hs2.finishDate) from "
    + WflWorkflowHistoryStep.class.getName() + " hs2 ");
  query2.append("where hs2.stepName = hs1.stepName and hs2.refId = hs1.refId)");`